# Remove all the entries in /etc/securetty except console, tty[0-9]* and vc/[0-9]*

Tags: text-processing, grep

I want to remove all the entries in `/etc/securetty` file except console, `tty[0-9]` and `vc/[09]`.

```
~]# cat /etc/securetty
console
vc/1
vc/2
vc/3
vc/4
vc/5
vc/6
vc/7
vc/8
vc/9
vc/10
vc/11
tty1
tty2
tty3
tty4
tty5
tty6
tty7
tty8
tty9
tty10
tty11
ttyS0
ttysclp0
```

I tried `egrep` command to collect the output. But I don't know how to get only 1-9 "tty or vc/"

```
~]# egrep "console|vc/|tty" /etc/securetty
```

Please help me get the output like below

```
~]# cat /etc/securetty
console
vc/1
vc/2
vc/3
vc/4
vc/5
vc/6
vc/7
vc/8
vc/9
tty1
tty2
tty3
tty4
tty5
tty6
tty7
tty8
tty9
```

Answer (score 2):

Almost there!

```
egrep 'console|vc/[0-9]$|tty[0-9]$' /etc/securetty
```

A general tip is to use single quotes rather than double quotes unless you need variables to be substituted.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me.

```
# sed '/^console$\|^vc\/[1-9]$\|^tty[1-9]$/!d' /etc/securetty
```

After reviewing, you can use the `-i` flag for `sed` to replace the file in place. Always backup your file first though!

Answer (score 0):

Giving `grep` multiple patterns, each with the `-e` option, will effectively do an OR between them.  Here I'm also using `grep` with its `-x` option to get it to match complete lines:

```bash
$ grep -x -e console -e 'tty[0-9]' -e 'vc/[0-9]' /etc/securetty
console
vc/1
vc/2
vc/3
vc/4
vc/5
vc/6
vc/7
vc/8
vc/9
tty1
tty2
tty3
tty4
tty5
tty6
tty7
tty8
tty9
```

I have corrected the `vc/[09]` pattern, making it `vc/[0-9]`, which is what I assume you meant.

Would you also want `tty` and `vc` device names with numbers `10` and `11` (or any higher integer number), use e.g. `tty[0-9]*` and `vc[0-9]*` as the patterns instead.